# Possible to get Visual Studio IDE screen position/size from DTE/Extensibility?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I'd like to get the current position/size of the Visual Studio IDE from within a VS Extension. The Windows events return the info on the 'panels' within the IDE, but not the overall IDE 'frame' itself.

I've created a windows forms 'floating' toolbar that I wish to lock to the IDE's movement around the screen, so ideally it would be returned by some type of DTE/IDE/Moved events.

Using VS Extension WFP panels/controls is not an option, hence my need to use Windows Forms for the UI of my Extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the main WPF Visual Studio [Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) using System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.

Comment: Thank you Sergey, that give me what I needed. For completeness, it looks like I can also use:   package.GetService(Of EnvDTE._DTE, EnvDTE._DTE).Application.MainWindow
....but your method is a bit more concise.